# manifest merger issue come when android studio 3.2 updated on 3.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, material-design, build.gradle

> i want to use latest android studio and i imported old version code
>   and update android studio after updation i have faced following error
>   after gradle android studio update

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
 [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
 AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91   is also present at
 [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).    Suggestion: add
 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element
 at AndroidManifest.xml:5:1-38:15 to override.
```

> I added one tag that mentioned in above error added in manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"         
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.digiskillslms.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

> but after that one another error occur kindly suggest me to resolve
>   this error i am stuck from one day before

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
```

> My gradle file is

```
     compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.digiskills.com.digiskillsapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev205-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
//    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> finally i solved my issue by replacing this one

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

Comment: `28.0.0` is the stable version. `alpha3` is not. Check my answer.

Comment: but 28.0.0 i added already you can check my question this version have error thats why we use previous version some days

Comment: Yes i saw it. The 28.0.0 might have this issue which is recommended to migrate to androidx. That's why..

Comment: i am trying your answer if it meaningful for me then i definately upvote you

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, to see what is the error, you can see the merged Manifest File in Android studio

1. Go on your manifest file

[image]

2. Click on the bottom tab "Merged Manifest"

[image]

3. On the right screen, in "Other Manifest Files", check for any error due to graddle

Answer (score 0):

Adding :  `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to `AndoridManifest.xml` didn't solve the issue to me either.

As [mentioned here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/193), and also here ([Getting Started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)) you'll probably will need to go to :

```
Refactor -> Migrate to Android X
```

And after that, it will be fine to use.

<sub>Note that you'll also need to change xml codes in the xml side.</sub>

For example (those should start by `androidx`):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:appComponentFactory` to your manifest

```
<application
  android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
  tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท  I mean `android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory` not just `tools:replace`